# Differentiation Chain Rule for Quaternion Functions of Quaternions

Tags: derivatives, quaternions, chain-rule

I am trying to calculate the time derivative of a quaternion function:

$$\mathbf{p}\left(t\right)=\left(\mathbf{q}\left(t\right)\right)^{\tau}$$

Where I've used bold font to indicate that $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ are each quaternions, while $\tau$ is just a scalar (not limited to integers). What I would like to be able to do is apply some sort of effective chain rule for quaternionic differentiation to calculate the time derivative:

$$\dot{\mathbf{p}}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{p}}{\partial\mathbf{q}}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{q}}$$

Where the dot operator ($\cdot$) represents the usual quaternion multiplication. With some effort, I believe that I have shown that $\mathbf{p}$ is quaternionic holomorphic and that its quaternionic derivative with respect to $\mathbf{q}$ is exactly what you'd expect:

$$\frac{\partial\mathbf{p}}{\partial\mathbf{q}} = \tau\mathbf{q}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{p} = \tau\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{q}^{-1}=\tau\mathbf{q}^{\tau-1}$$

Unfortunately, when I try different functions for $\mathbf{q}\left(t\right)$ and the above chain rule, I don't get the actual rate of change of the function $\mathbf{p}\left(t\right)$, which I am estimating numerically. I understand that, if I really want to, I should be able to calculate the full time derivative of $\mathbf{p}$ without using the chain rule. But life would be a lot easier for me if I didn't have to resort to that in all cases.

Is there a quaternionic version of the chain rule that I can use to simplify some of my research? Please help!

If you're interested, here's a link to a PDF where I verify the quaternionic holomorphicity of $\mathbf{p}$: https://www.scribd.com/document/352235082/Quaternionic-Holomorphicity-Verification

Comment: How are you even evaluating $q(t)^\tau$ numerically?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed, since I posted the question, I've noticed that $dp = p(q + dq) - p(q)$ is different depending on the direction of the imaginary component of $dq$.

Comment: I wasn't evaluating $p$ numerically. I was using $p(t) = q(t)^\tau = e^{\tau log(q(t))} = e^{\tau \theta_q \hat{n_q}} = cos(\tau \theta_q) + \hat{n_q} sin(\tau \theta_q)$. I was simply approximating the time derivative of $p$ with finite differences.

Comment: Since $\theta$ in the expression $q=e^{\theta n}$ is only defined up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$, in general $e^{\tau \theta n}$ may be more than one thing depending on which $\theta$ you pick. Presumably you are picking $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$, in which case $q^{\tau}$ is discontinuous when $q$ is a negative real number. (I assume $\tau$ is real.) But if $q$ is defined in terms of already-given $\theta$ and $n$, you can simply differentiate $\cos(\tau \theta)+n\sin(\tau\theta)$ using the chain rule with $\theta$ and $n$ as functions of $t$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Since quaternions admit a matrix representation, this [blog post](https://nhigham.com/2020/12/08/what-is-a-fractional-matrix-power/) by Nick Higham will be relevant when computing $q(t)^\tau\;$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First**, even for *complex numbers*, the function $q^\tau$ has complications in even being *defined* when $\tau$ is not an integer (you have to use branch cuts in the plane, which forces $q^\tau$ to be discontinuous as almost all points on the branch). For example, $q^{1/2}$ with respect to the standard choice of branch cut (the negative real axis) is discontinuous at negative one: as $q\to-1$ from the upper half plane, we get $q^{1/2}\to i$, whereas as $q\to -1$ from the lower half plane, we get $q^{1/2}\to -i$. The situation becomes even worse if you're letting $\tau$ be nonreal. None of these complications go away when we work with quaternions.

**Second**, even if $\tau$ is an integer, no $q^\tau$ is *not* generally left or right holomorphic as a function of the quaternion variable $q$. I am not going to bother reading  the cumbersome derivation in the scribd page because this is a well-established fact. It will be a smooth map between real manifolds if you forget the quaternion multiplication operation though, so it's possible you're confusing holomorphic with  that weaker condition.

Here's an example: consider $f(q)=q^2$. Write out the right derivative as follows:

$$ \begin{array} \big[f(q+h)-f(q)\big]h^{-1} & =\big[(q+h)^2-q^2\big]h^{-1} \\ & = [hq+qh+h^2]h^{-1} \\ & = hqh^{-1}+q+h \end{array} $$

Note that $hqh^{-1}$ does not depend on the magnitude of $h$, only on its phase and the direction of its imaginary part (its vector component). Indeed, if $h=\varepsilon e^{\theta u}$ is its polar form, $hqh^{-1}$ will be the result of rotating $q$'s vector component around the vector $u$ by an angle of $2\theta$. As such, the limit of $hqh^{-1}$ as $h\to0$ will depend on which direction $h\to0$ in, and  thus the limit does not exist.

In fact, it is known the only left and right holomorphic quaternion functions (with domain all of $\mathbb{H}$) are the affine functions $qa+b$ and $aq+b$ respectively.

**Third**, even if $\tau$ is a whole number, the time derivative of $q(t)^\tau$ is still not what you say it is, essentially because $q(t)$ and $q'(t)$ generally have no reason to commute. However, even in a noncommutative setting we *still* have the product rule (*exercise*: prove the product rule without assuming $f(t_1)$ ever commutes with $g(t_2)$ for any $t_1$ or $t_2$), which can be used to give

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle \frac{dq^2}{dt} & \displaystyle =\frac{dq}{dt}q+q\frac{dq}{dt} \\ \displaystyle \frac{dq^3}{dt} & \displaystyle = \frac{dq}{dt}q^2+q\frac{dq}{dt}q+q^2\frac{dq}{dt} \\ \displaystyle \frac{dq^4}{dt} & \displaystyle = \frac{dq}{dt}q^3+q\frac{dq}{dt}q^2+q^2\frac{dq}{dt}q+q^3\frac{dq}{dt} \end{array} $$

and so on. Thus,

$$ \frac{dq^n}{dt}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k \frac{dq}{dt} q^{n-k-1} $$

by induction. We may obtain time derivatives of negative powers indirectly:

$$ 0 = \frac{d}{dt}(1)=\frac{d}{dt} (q^nq^{-n})=\frac{dq^n}{dt}q^{-n}+q^n\frac{dq^{-n}}{dt} $$

$$ \implies \frac{dq^{-n}}{dt}=-q^{-n}\frac{dq^n}{dt}q^{-n}. $$

Comment: I see that this is more complicated than I initially thought.

Comment: Fortunately, I've found that if I restrict $q$ to the unit quaternions, then I have been able to find $\dot{p}$ assuming that I have $\dot{q}$:

$$\dot{p} = \left(\tau \dot{\theta_q} \hat{n_q}\right) \cdot p + v_p \dot{\hat{n_q}}$$

Where $log(q) = \theta_q \hat{n_q}$, $p = u_p + \vec{v_p}$, and $v_p = |\vec{v_p}|$. So far, this has worked for any $0 \leq \tau \leq 1/2$.